# why does my ubuntu screen sometimes tile up when i run a program

Tags: screen

[image]

This is a pic of the issue. Sometimes when I run a program usually my screen tiles up and as time goes on it will get worse to the point where I cannot see whats being displayed on my screen.

It has been going on every time I open up a new window. Can this be resolved or am I just going to have to live with this annoying bug?

I love Linux and I want to get this problem resolved. If anyone could help I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: As currently written, this question doesn't have enough information. Please include a screenshot or error messages to help describe the problem in more detail. Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen under other operating systems with the same hardware?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-abrams No it doesn't happen on other OS.

Comment: Sounds like a GART problem then.

Comment: what is a GART problem?? just wondering.

Comment: and how will i be able to fix this "GART" problem?

Comment: What's your video card model?

Comment: @EricCarvalho the card model is PCI-E x1 and i have a dell dimension e310.